# Ansible: remove older elements from list of dicts

Tags: ansible

I have a list of dicts in Ansible (in my case a list of certificates from AWS ACM). There are multiple entries for attribute1 (domain name) with different attribute2 (expiry date). I want to filter the list to only contain the one entry with attribute1 that has the greatest attribute2.

This is how the structure of the list looks like (simplified):

```
[
  {
    "domain_name": "example.com",
    "not_after": "2024-07-31T01:59:59+02:00"
  },
  {
    "domain_name": "example2.com",
    "not_after": "2024-07-31T01:59:59+02:00"
  },
  {
    "domain_name": "example.com",
    "not_after": "2023-07-15T01:59:59+02:00"
  }
]
```

I want to get a list with just one entry for each domain, and that should be the entry with the greatest `not_after` date. I know how to sort or select or filter lists based on attributes, but I can't figure out a way to achieve this.

Is this possible with built-in filters? Or do I have to write a custom filter or run through some custom loop?

Comment: Is your question, "how do I sort a list by date in ansible?", or are you asking something else? You said, "I know how to sort or select or filter lists based on attributes", which sounds like you've already solved the problem.

Comment: No the question was how to sort and uniq it. The accepted answer does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible/Jinja filters support attributes. So, at the first glance, if I did not miss anything, first we can sort the whole dict by the expiration date, and then select the items by unique domain name:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Sort the certificates by their expiration date
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    certificates:
      [
        {
          "domain_name": "example.com",
          "not_after": "2024-07-31T01:59:59+02:00"
        },
        {
          "domain_name": "example2.com",
          "not_after": "2024-07-31T01:59:59+02:00"
        },
        {
          "domain_name": "example.com",
          "not_after": "2023-07-15T01:59:59+02:00"
        } 
      ]
  tasks:
    - name: Sort by attribute
      set_fact:
        certificates: >
          {{
            certificates 
            | sort(attribute='not_after', reverse=true)
            | unique(attribute='domain_name')
          }}
```

To be honest, looks too simple, but seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. Maybe it was already too late yesterday, but I couldn't come up with the sort+unique combination (and probably didn't know the unique-by-attribute filter).